# How to change the scope of product Quantity from Global to Website level?

Tags: magento2, product, inventory, quantity

I am using `Magento 2.2.6 Open Source Edition`, a single product has been selected for 3 websites in `Product in Websites` section, I would like to have different quantities of the product for each website.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple, open your product, select website store scope as per screenshot, now you can fill different quantities for each store/website.

[image]

Comment: as you can see the scop of the Quantity is global so changing it affects all the websites and store-views, the question says how to have different Quantities of the product for each website.

Comment: Yes, You can change in db directly (I don't recommend it) you need to change the field is_global to 2 from the table catalog_eav_attribute for the record with the id the same as your attribute has in the eav_attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that first in Stores > Attributes > Product > Attribute Code: quantity_and_stock_status and edit the scope to Store View or in your case Website. See the following screenshot: Accept the solution if its works for you.
[image]

Comment: That is the scope of status and doesn't work as solution for my question, it has no affect on the Quantity field.

Comment: I have changed Stores > Attributes > Product > Attribute Code: quantity_and_stock_status to the website but the Quantity field and stock_status still shown as the global and changing value of quantity for one website changes the value of second website.

Comment: @ReshadZazai I am also facing "changing value of quantity for one website changes the value of second website." issue. Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Does anyone gets a solution for this? Is it a bug of Magento 2?